# shebang groovy giving error

Tags: shell, groovy

I have the following lines in my .sh file

```
#! /usr/bin/env /Users/myuser/Development/tools/groovy

println "this is a test"
```

env: /Users/myuser/tools/groovy: Permission denied

when I run the command /usr/bin/env groovy I don't get any errors. Any clues why it would be happening on an OS X ?

Comment: I copied your example and it works here (10.7.4). Did you check your permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick is to avoid having to specify the full path to the interpeter. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) (and [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454)) for more information. Since you're specifying the full absolute path anyway, you might as well use:

```
#!/Users/myuser/Development/tools/groovy
```

As for why this isn't working, most likely you have a `groovy` command somewhere else in your `$PATH`, and `/usr/bin/env groovy` is invoking that other copy.

This:

```
type -a groovy
```

will tell you which `groovy` executable is in your `$PATH`. And this:

```
ls -l /Users/myuser/Development/tools/groovy
```

should tell you why you're getting the "Permission denied" error; most likely that file is not executable.

Another possibility: some systems limit the length of a `#!` line. I don't know whether OSX does so. If it does, the path to your `groovy` command might be truncated. If this is the problem, you might consider moving or copying the `groovy` command to a directory with a shorter absolute path.

Comment: As well as `type -a groovy`, `which groovy` will tell you it's path. Possibly a little easier to remember.

Comment: @doelleri: `type -a` can be a bit more informative; `which` doesn't report aliases or functions.

Comment: Thanks that worked. There were no multiple versions but I had an alias which actually pointed to the actual binary file. When I changed it to use the actual binary, it worked.